# Fix override mistake

Tags: java

I try to run a programm but i get those four errors.

> TestCusomer.java:25: error: toString() in Invoice cannot override toString() in Object (same thing at line 49)

and

> line 59 cannot find symbol . myCustomer.setTrn(112233778)
>
> line 60 cannot find symbol . myCustomer.setPersentage(150)

My programm is the following:

```
      class Invoice
      {


      int trn; //TAX REGISTRATION NUMBER
      int persentage;
      public Invoice{}

      public int setTrn(int trn){
        this.trn = trn;
      } 

      public int getTrn(){
         return trn;
      }

      public void setPersentage(int persentage){
          this.persentage = persentage;
      } 

      public int getPersentage(){
          return persentage;
      }

      String toString(){
          System.out.println(trn+" : "+persentage);
      }
 }   

 class Customer{

    int trn;
    int charging= 0;

    public Customer(int trn){
        this.trn = trn;
    }

    public int charge(int amount){
        charging = charging + amount;
    } 

    public int charge(int amount , int trn){
        if (this.trn == trn){
            charging = charging + amount;
        }
    }

    String toString(){
        System.out.println(trn+" : "+charging);
    }
}

 class TestCustomer
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Customer myCustomer = new Customer(112233778);
        myCustomer.charge(100);
        myCustomer.setTrn(112233778);
        myCustomer.setPersentage(150);

        System.out.println(myCustomer);
    }
}
```

Comment: `toString()` must be declared public because that is how is defined in `Object`. Your other errors occur because those methods don't exist in the `Customer` class.

Answer (score 2):

few things,

1. You need to declare the `toString` method public
2. You need to return a String in your `toString` methods
3. I strongly suggest you add the [@Override](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) notation when you override a method to ensure that you actually override the method
4. The `cannot find symbol...` happen because those methods are not defined in `Customer`, you have those in `Invoice`

Comment: is there a way to call those methods even if they are in a different class?

Comment: sure, since Invoice is an object, you can make an invoice object in Customer (much like you did for Customer in main) and call them through that.

Comment: oh i see , can you explain the @Override thing a bit more?

Comment: @Bill  `@Override` is a java notation to let both the compiler and the programmer know that the method overrides the method of a parent class (in this case the parent is `Object`)
Have a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html)

Comment: ok! i am not sure how to make the new object in Invoice! I also get a "missing return statement in line 11" !

Comment: @Bill that missing return is to point 2. And you would make the new Invoice object you made the Customer object in main. Then you can add accessors to Customer

Comment: @FluffmeisterGeneral I like to pretend it is needed, as otherwise it might be forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

Your toString() methods need to return String objects. You are outputting a string in them but not returning a string. Also make them public.

For example, your toString() method for the Invoice class should be:

```
public String toString()
{
    return trn  + " : " + persentage;
}
```

And for your second problem (cannot find symbols), those methods are in the Invoice class and not in the Customer class so they cannot be called on a Customer object.

Comment: i did :

public String toString(){
  System.out.println(trn+" : "+persentage);
 }

Comment: but i get this : missing return statement }

Comment: Your toString methods need to return a string object. You are outputting a string object in them instead of returning it.

Comment: @DermotBlair I am not sure why you voted down but I vote u up cuz ur answer sounds right to me

Comment: Thanks @KickButtowski. I am not sure who voted down but I think it is correct as well.